# AWS S3 presigned-url: How to make sure that the file type is correct?

Tags: javascript, security, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The HTTP headers (`Content-Type`) and the metadata that an HTML file input returns (`file.type`) are not reliable and could be easily bypassed by hackers. So how do you make sure that the file that is going to be uploaded to S3 has the correct file type when using AWS s3 `presigned[-post]-url`s?

There are packages like [`file-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) that can detect the actual type of a file. But the problem is that in order to detect the file type they need the content of the file as a buffer or Uint8Array. So I have to send the file twice. Once to the server to detect the file type and the `presigned-url` (if it has a correct type), and once for actually uploading it to s3, which is obviously a bad thing.

Comment: You can let the server act like a proxy and upload the file for you instead of sending the file the second time tho.

Comment: That genuinely makes sense. I may end up doing so but let's see if people have another solution for that. thanks.

Comment: You either need to have the verification server send the file to S3, or verify the content with something like a Lambda after it lands in S3.  Otherwise, if you verify the file, then ask the client to upload to S3, there's little preventing the client from sending a good file to the verification endpoint, and a bad file to S3.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I'm working on it and when it completes I will answer the question and mark it as solved.